# Making list of achievements?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if this has been done before on Arqade, and if it helps people or not. I am assuming making a list of achievements e.g. will not really help at all as there are many websites online, so what are the standards to creating "lists" of things from games?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thats something that, IMO, is not what Arqade is. We are not a site where we do unprompted lists or guides.

We are a QA site. So we only do 'guides' when someone does ask to be helped with the achievement in question.

It's basically our niche.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, I was just slightly unclear about it :)

Comment: @DialFrost There was a [movement](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12094/124566) a few years ago to try and get the (now discontinued) SE Documentation feature in Arqade to support what you're requesting, but alas this never came to be

Comment: In some way, yes it could bring people to this site, but at the same time, I'd say that the Q&A part is what is making Arqade unique. A guide sections will only make us another GameFaqs.

Comment: Powerpyx would have us forever beat, at least for PS trophies :)